# Named pipe in form of a directory using FUSE

Tags: go, fuse

I would like to create a FUSE file system which accepts any kind of write operation to any path inside the file system. Kind of like a named pipe, but in form of a directory.

```
echo test > bar         # consumes "test"
echo test > bar/foo     # consumes "test", even though the directory "bar" hasn't been created
echo test > x/y/z/test  # consumes "test", even though the directories "x/y/z" haven't been created
```

I'm using [bazil.org/fuse](https://bazil.org/fuse) for the implementation. The problem that I'm facing is that when an application wants to write to `foo/bar` inside my file system, it checks whether `foo` is a directory, then whether `bar` is a file. Unfortunately, I can't know upfront whether `foo` should be a file or a directory.

My `Attr` function looks as follows:

```
func (d *Dir) Attr(ctx context.Context, a *fuse.Attr) error {
        a.Inode = 1
        a.Mode = os.ModeDir | 0755
}
```

This code is specific for a directory node type, due to `os.ModeDir`. I want this to work for directories or files.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What would you expect from the following sequence of writes: `echo test > foo/bar; echo test > foo`?

Comment: What about the other way around: `echo test > foo; echo test > foo/bar`?

Comment: @Leon: both commands should execute normally, in both cases the FUSE file system should accept a write operation to a file called `foo` or `foo/bar`, respectively.

Comment: That means that in your use case you are only going to issue write requests and never read back. Is that correct?

Comment: @Leon: exactly. The file system consumes all write requests internally, but it is not required to read anything back.

Comment: Please clarify: `foo/bar` - is a file named `bar` in directory `foo`? Or maybe you trying to bypass linux limitation in filenames and `foo/bar` is actually `foo\/bar`?

Comment: @AlexYu correct, `foo/bar` is a file `bar` in directory `foo`, not file `foo\/bar`.

Comment: @waitan Hm. And what prevents you from `os.MkDirAll(filepath.Dir("foo/bar")` before attempt to write into file?

Comment: @AlexYu I want the file system to be transparent when looking at it from the client-side. Creating the directory `foo` before writing to the file `foo/bar` would solve the problem, because this way the file system will know that `foo` is a directory, being able to set `a.Mode = os.ModeDir | 0755`. However, the file system should act as if the directory already exists, making it possible to directly write to the file in the first place.

Comment: A possible example would be to mount the file system on top of `/var/log`. A application then wants to write to `/var/log/app/debug.log`, but the application already expects `/var/log/app` to be a directory. So I just want to allow the application to write to `/var/log/app/debug.log`, even if the file doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem that I'm facing is that when an application wants to write to `foo/bar` inside my file system, it checks whether `foo` is a directory, then whether `bar` is a file. Unfortunately, I can't know upfront whether `foo` should be a file or a directory.

Given these constraints, solving your problem is impossible.

A file system node can be either a file or a directory; sometimes neither, but never both at the same time. Because your FUSE driver cannot know in advance whether an application performing the `getattr` request means to recurse inside the node until it actually tries to, you cannot know whether it should pretend to be a file or a directory.

Your best options seem to be:

- hardcode application-specific virtual directory structure into your FUSE driver
- implement application-specific heuristics in your FUSE driver
- make your FUSE driver memorise `getattr` requests and construct a virtual directory tree by trial and error (and keep re-running the application until it works)